# Automatic pulbishing of a sharepoint site

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2007

We are beginning work on sharepoint 2007 site and I am looking for ways to automate its publish during the nightly build process.
Currently we are using WSPBuilder to manually build and deploy features/components. Is it possible to script the WSPBuilder to run automatically? Are there any other tools available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to build a SharePoint Timer Job that monitors a folder for new WSPs and then, when the Job finds them, installs and deploys them to the Site/Site Collection.